# VS Code: Is it possible to have an extension with user interface (Html/css/JS)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to create an extension with user interface for visual studio code.

I like to have an editor for a json file and I like to have some UI for it.

Like google chrome extensions with HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT.

Does VS Code supports these kind of extensions?

Comment: Duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481386/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-in-vscode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, VSCode does not provide this level of extension integration. However, if you still plan to edit the JSON using the text editor, but want to "render" it in some way, that is possible.  You can use a `TextDocumentContentProvider` to provide a read-only view of your JSON file.  For a similar example, look at the [CSS Properties Preview example extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/previewhtml-sample).

Comment: VS Code is kind of a Electron project I guess, do you have any idea why they don't add such extensions?

Comment: im guessing that this is now possible with the Webview API https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview

Comment: @StefanStoichev i have a vscode extension which creates dotnet projects using Quickpick utilities. Can i change that to buttons using webview ? if yes how can i navigate from html to typescript as my whole extension is in typescript.

Comment: @srikarkulkarni i dont know. I was just searching for something and realised that the webview is now live (was not live at the moment when the question was posted)