# How to create a custom dialog in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension for VSCode, and I want to display a custom dialog to help the user configure an ini file.

Is it possible to create a custom dialog with labels and inputs?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot create new UI elements, but if you want to get inputs from the user you can use code like below:

```ts
let options: InputBoxOptions = {
    prompt: "Label: ",
    placeHolder: "(placeholder)"
}

window.showInputBox(options).then(value => {
    if (!value) return;
    answer1 = value;
    // show the next dialog, etc.
});
```

This will use the same UI as the command palette (when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, or any of the other commands that open the input box at the top).

Comment: is this still true in 2017? Also I wonder if there is reference to "UI policy" of vscode or smth where they discuss why this is not yet part of api or whether they plan to implement it in the future?

Comment: Yes this is still true. You can read the principles behind this decision here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/patterns-and-principles

Comment: "We do not provide direct access to the underlying UI DOM to extension writers. With VS Code, we’re continually trying to optimize use of the underlying web technologies...and we will continue to tune our use of the DOM as these technologies and our product evolve...we run extensions in their own host process and prevent direct access to the DOM. VS Code also includes a built-in set of UI components for common scenarios such as IntelliSense, so that these experiences are consistent across programming languages and extensions and extension developers do not need to build their own."

Comment: that's great info! However they don't say anything there about plan to introduce modals or custom dialog boxes (of course they say that they don't want each extension dev to reinvent the wheel, but adding "Modal dialog" functionality may be useful.. )

Comment: The [color picker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=anseki.vscode-color) extension pulls up a dialog box perfectly

Comment: That looks neat, thanks for the heads up Jeff. However, they don't do that using the standard api, they spawn a separate electron app in its own process and use ipc to communicate between it and the main color picker extension process.